# psycopg2 copy_expert and copy_from using file object detecting int as float

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, csv, import, psycopg2

I'm trying to use `psycopg2` to bulk copy csv files to table using file object and it is reading what are ints in the csv file as floats. My understanding is that I can't pass a dataframe to `copy_from` or `copy_expert` and cast correctly. How can I cast data types during the file read or resolve this issue altogether using a different method? I need to specify size in order to overcome limits the database server has. Thanks!

```
    sql_statement = "COPY " + table_name + " FROM STDIN with csv"
    with open(data_dir + r'/' + file) as f:
        next(f)
        curs.copy_expert(sql_statement, f, size = 8192)
        conn.commit()
    curs.close()
```

> DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "1.0"

PS: the data import works when writing line by line using `df.to_sql`. If I change the datatype of that specific column to double precision the import succeeds

Comment: Did you have any success with this? I'm encountering the same issue.

Comment: No I have just been manually changing the column to match the right type